# Redirecting my website to another hostname from http to https

Tags: redirect, iis, https

I'm trying to redirect my internal website to another hostname and from http to https.
Which I'm trying to achieve is when the user hits me.aaa.bbb.ccc, it redirects him to https://me-aaa.bbb.ccc
so the hostname is changed to "-" instead of "." and also it is redirected to https.

I'v used http redirect in IIS as well as this rewrite rule

```
<rewrite>
              <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect to https">
                  <match url=".*" />
                  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Redirect" url="https://me-aaa.bbb.ccc/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
                </rule>
              </rules>
            </rewrite>
```

Can anyone helps me with this please?!

Comment: Which issue did you receive? Your rule looks correct

Comment: It does nothing actually. It only opens the website me.aaa.bbb.cc without redirecting and without converting to https.  These is one thing I forgot to mention, I’m having the two bindings in the same site. Is it ok or we hve to have them in two separate sites!?